# How to Benchmark Cloud Storage Systems such as Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, benchmarking, cloud-storage

I have developed a cloud storage system that uses the same API structure as Amazon S3. Now I want to run some performance tests on **getting object data and object metadata**. In such a way that I can compare my system with Amazon S3, OpenStack storage and other systems.

I have looked at some common file system benchmark tools, there is too much work to convert them for Cloud Storage systems.

I am looking for some benchmark tools similar to [SIEGE](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), that not only can performance http requests, but also have some workload simulation features. For example, one simulation can be storing an entire static HTML website in the Cloud Storage then performance some workload stress test etc.

Can someone help and suggest some existing framework or tools that can be relatively easy to be fit for such cloud storage system benchmark scenario?

Comment: Note that S3 is a dynamic system, so doing a 'quick benchmark' will give you terrible numbers. Here is an article about a similar test run on ELB: http://www.rightscale.com/blog/cloud-management-best-practices/benchmarking-load-balancers-cloud

Answer (score 6):

You can probably look into [COSBench](https://github.com/intel-cloud/cosbench), which is a tool to benchmark object storage cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

[COSBench](https://github.com/intel-cloud/cosbench) was a good solution but is getting old. The last effective commit is in [2017](https://github.com/intel-cloud/cosbench/commits/master).

I'd suggest:

- [s3-benchmark](https://github.com/dvassallo/s3-benchmark)
- [os-benchmark](https://github.com/cloudmercato/os-benchmark)

The 2nd one is mainly made by myself. It's on ongoing development and aims to test more than just S3 Object storages. The test suite contains:

- Upload
- Download
- Multi Upload
- Video streaming simulation
- Ping/TCPping/Traceroute/TCPTraceroute
- cURL details

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use the `fio` http engine instead of the above mentioned recommendation. It's is much more mature than what was previously suggested and it supports S3 and is very configurable.

Example job: https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/examples/http-s3.fio